# GHCi load a file and redefine one of its functions in the repl

Tags: haskell

Imagine I load a file (not a module) in GHCi like this

```
:l file.hs
```

and that inside the file there are two functions `f` and `g`, and that `f` has some bug (e.g., bad result) and that `g` calls `f`.

How can I redefine `f` with a correct version at the GHCi REPL, and make `g` call the new version without having to change or reload the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't**.

When loading the file in the repl it's as if the definitions were in a separate module and thus `g` will not look for the `f` you define at the repl, even if from your point of view your definition hides the original `f` function.

---

Haskell uses *lexical scoping*, while what you suggest is a *dynamic scoping* feature. See [lexical scoping vs dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope).
It's completely impractical to modify the repl to compile code using lexical scoping and then allow people to modify it by using dynamic scoping. Hence it's not done and what you ask is impossible.

Comment: Isn't there some obscure GHC API for doing this?

Comment: In this case, GHC could replace `f` with its new version, if this had the same type signature. I really do not understand why this is so difficult ...

Comment: It should, I think, be possible to do this by actually missing the binding, as long as the module is interpreted and not compiled. The big challenge: any time this is done, the type checker will need to be run to make sure everything is okay. That said, the practical answer is to run `stack ghci` or `cabal repl` within an environment like emacs that makes rapid development convenient.

Comment: @dfeuer I am a newbie in Haskell, so right now it is not clear how can I do what you suggest. Do you have time for a comprehensive answer with an example, a newbie friendly? Thank you for your response.